# Get the any words contained inside of quotes

Tags: php, string

Sample of data `$string = '"word","foo","bar","foobar","barfoo"';`

Before I only used these:

```
str_replace('"','',$string) 
explode(',',$string)
```

I remove all of the quotes and proceed to split them by comma, but then I saw sample of data:

`$string = '"word","foo","bar","foobar","bar,foo"';`

Since I rely on comma to get the data, my code will be wrong.

Is there a php function that could get the substring inside of two given characters? Or if there is not, any advice on what functions I'll need to do this properly?

Comment: Where does the string come from?

Comment: It comes from an api, I only summarized it to be inside of string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For PHP >=5.3

There is a function called [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) for parsing CSV string into array. This also works if you have char `"` in your string (see `foo""bar`), where simple regex will fail; Or where you don't have quotes/enclosure (see `word`).

#### Code:

```php
$string = 'word,"foo","bar","foo""bar","bar,foo"';
print_r( str_getcsv($string) );
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => word
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
    [3] => foo"bar
    [4] => bar,foo
)
```

### For PHP < 5.3

A little modified example from [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) comments (*see other examples to*) area :

```php
function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $escape = '\\') {
    $handle = fopen('php://memory', 'rw');
    fwrite($handle, $input);
    fseek($handle, 0);
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escape);
    fclose($handle);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This is a new function, I don't know if the client is using a php that can handle this function but it does it work quite well and it's a one-liner thank you sir

Comment: For me php 5.3 is old ;) I have added example for php<5.3. You can even see other examples on the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match_all() function:

```
$string = '"word","foo","bar","foobar","bar,foo"';
$pattern = '#"(.*?)"#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => word
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
    [3] => foobar
    [4] => bar,foo
)
```

or if you want to match all words:

```
$pattern = '#([^",]+)#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => word
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
    [3] => foobar
    [4] => bar
    [5] => foo
)
```

Comment: This will fail if string will have `"` inside; example = `foo""bar`

Comment: @Glavić: there should be something constant as delimiter, otherwise, we can't extract the words

Comment: Delimiter is not `"`, it is `,`. Enclosure is `"` and escape character is `"` or `\ `. Put all that in the regex and it will rock ;)

Answer (score 1):

The function str_getcsv() is available since PHP 5.3.0.

For lower versions of PHP you can use something like this:

```
if (!function_exists('str_getcsv')) {

    function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $escape = null, $eol = null) {
        $temp = fopen("php://memory", "rw");
        fwrite($temp, $input);
        fseek($temp, 0);
        $r = array();
        while (( $data = fgetcsv($temp, 4096, $delimiter, $enclosure)) !== false) {
            $r[] = $data;
        }
        fclose($temp);
        return $r;
    }

}
```

But be careful with the function str_getcsv - if the enclosure is " test it for this case:

```
$string = '"wo"rd","fo"o","b"ar","fo"obar","ba"rfoo"';
```

I think that quotation mark inside your data have to be escaped before you use it with str_getcsv() function.

**EDIT**

I made some tests:

```
$str1 = '"wo"rd","foo"';
$str2 = '"wo""rd","foo"';
$str3 = '"wo\"rd","foo"';

$test_arr1 = str_getcsv($str1);
$test_arr2 = str_getcsv($str2);
$test_arr3 = str_getcsv($str3);

print_r($test_arr1);
print_r($test_arr2);
print_r($test_arr3);
```

The output is:

Array ( [0] => word" [1] => foo )

Array ( [0] => wo"rd [1] => foo )

Array ( [0] => wo\"rd [1] => foo )

T. B.

Comment: Are people still on <5.3 versions? God damn, I am already moving to 5.5 on production ;) And your example of `$string` is incorrect, because if you have character in string that is the same as enclosure, you must escape it with escape character; incorrect `"fo"o"`, correct `"fo""o"` or `"fo\"o"`.

Comment: + `str_getcsv` and `fgetcsv` are returning identical on `"fo"obar"`, `"fo""obar"` or `"fo\"obar"`. + this function returns array in 2nd level, try it.

Comment: @Glavić - you are not right - my string is correct because it is enclosed by ' not by ". And yes some people are still on PHP 5.2. From my experience some intranet applications in some companies are still running on PHP 5.2 :-(.

Comment: I am not talking about string enclosure, but parsing string chunks like `"word"`, `"foobar"` and etc. where `"` is enclosure.

Comment: @Glavić - you wrote that str_getcsv and fgetcsv are returning identical on "fo"obar", "fo""obar" or "fo\"obar". I made some tests - see above.

Comment: You are saying one thing and writing code for other thing... Where in your example is compare output for `str_getcsv` and `fgetcsv`? You are only running function `str_getcsv`. See my example = http://codepad.viper-7.com/nKnjXT

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you exactly. You are right. I just pointed out to be careful for this $string = '"wo"rd","foo"';

Answer (score 0):

You can split by `","` instead after removing the beginning and the end separators.

```
$trimmed_string = trim($string, '\'"');
explode('","',$trimmed_string);
```

Comment: The problem is if there is a comma inside of a value, in index [4] it's "barfoo" right? Imagine it like "bar,foo" if I follow my code, it will become [4]=>"bar",[5]=>"foo"

Comment: No, you're splitting by `","`, not `,`.

Comment: Good idea, I upped your answer to remove the minus the other person did